# JavaMail don't read MimeMultipart emails

Tags: jakarta-mail

```
if (contentType.contains("multipart")) {
    // content may contain attachments
    Multipart multiPart = (Multipart) message.getContent();
    numberOfParts = multiPart.getCount();

    for (int partCount = 0; partCount < numberOfParts; partCount++) {

            BodyPart part = multiPart.getBodyPart(partCount);
        String disposition = part.getDisposition();
        InputStream inputStream = null;

        if (disposition == null)
        {


        MimeBodyPart mbp = (MimeBodyPart) multiPart.getBodyPart(partCount);
        if (mbp.getContent() instanceof MimeMultipart){

                MimeMultipart mmp = (MimeMultipart) mbp.getContent();

                messageContent = mmp.getBodyPart(0).getContent().toString();

            //System.out.println("bodyContent " + bodyContent);
        }
          else
        {        
                messageContent = multiPart.getBodyPart(partCount).getContent().toString();
         }
        }
        else if (Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(part.getDisposition())) {
            // this part is attachment
            String fileName = part.getFileName();
            attachFiles += fileName + ", ";
            //part.saveFile(saveDirectory + File.separator + fileName);
        }else if (Part.INLINE.equalsIgnoreCase(part.getDisposition())) {
            // this part is attachment
            String fileName = part.getFileName();
            attachFiles += fileName + ", ";
           // mbp.saveFile(saveDirectory + File.separator + fileName);
        }
        else {
            // this part may be the message content
            messageContent = part.getContent().toString();
        }
    }

    if (attachFiles.length() > 1) {
        attachFiles = attachFiles.substring(0, attachFiles.length() - 2);
    }
} else if (contentType.contains("text/plain") || contentType.contains("text/html")) {
    Object content = message.getContent();
    if (content != null) {messageContent = content.toString(); }
}
```

And now this type of message text / plain, text / html gets well. The problem is the email multipart / related when the message has attachments and content is HTML, then gets some news and some not. I noticed that it is dependent on this line:

messageContent = mmp.getBodyPart (0). getContent (). toString ();

If instead of "0" is "partCount" gets all but one particular, if instead of "0" is "1" gets me this one specific and does not charge others. numberOfParts this one particular message is "3" and the other "2". I have no idea what is wrong, maybe wrong parameters are passed?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what problem you're trying to solve, but just in case this [JavaMail FAQ entry](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#mainbody) might be helpful.

multipart/mixed and multipart/related are very similar in that they have one main part and a bunch of other parts usually thought of as "attachments".  Sometimes the disposition will tell you that it's an attachment, and sometimes it won't.  Some mailers aren't very consistent in their use of disposition.

One of the unusual cases is multipart/alternative, but it doesn't sound like that's the problem you're running in to.